# How come only the opening tag of this nav is red? Can't select it in css, but no errors are thrown

Tags: html

[image]

Disclaimer: I did remove the space after my class on the nav tag, it made no difference.

Like I said, seemingly simple problem, I hope. I can't select this nav element in CSS. I saw some stuff while looking this up about red tags meaning somethings deprecated, but I couldn't find anything about Nav being deprecated. Besides, it looked like a tag that was deprecated had red opening and closing tags, mine is just the opening tag. I'm pretty sure I've been opening and closing tags like these no problem, but maybe I missed something dumb...

I just meticulously checked for accidental extra characters I might have stuck somewhere, and checked if I opened and closed elements properly, I can't seem to find the issue and I'm a bit stumped now.

Comment: Red means invalid syntax. You didn't close previous div tag.

Comment: when you open a tag close it first then continue, to avoid this kind of errors.

Comment: I see what you're saying... facepalm, thanks a lot